How to distribute air from a small-diameter pipe across a much wider rectangular duct?
I have a humidifier comprised of about 20 vertical wicking sheets/gills (chromatography paper) evenly spaced by about 7mm from each other, placed inside of a rectangular duct. The duct ID is 150x150 mm in cross section, and the duct is 300mm long. This has been tested as a model system with a 140x140 box fan placed in front of the "gills". In a real-life situation, however, the air needs to come out of a 25mm ID tube, at a face velocity of about 10 m/s. The compressed air is driven by a centrifugal turbo, i.e. it is at a higher pressure than the "model" box fan.
What is the most cost-effective way to evenly distribute the air emanating from the 25mm tube across the cross section, with minimal power losses and simple manufacturing (i.e. I cannot afford a custom funnel plenum with numerous channels at this stage)?
I am thinking to direct the compressed air onto the 140x140 box fan (and thus to "chop" the air into turbulent flow) -- would this work? The fan is rated at a 10x higher flow, but 10x lower pressure (ballpark figures). Another method I have seen is to place a coarse filter screen in front of the compressesed air, but I wonder if this will put unnecessary stress on the turbo.
Thank you all in advance!

I think just a baffle plate in front of the stream would be enough, if the plenum is large enough.

Thank you, Tiger Guy I searched for this term and got mostly perforated plates. Could you give a link to a specific part as an example? I came up with an ackward gizmo based on two honeycomb grills, 20-mm deep, with 6mm cells. The first honeycomb is 150x25 mm, fused at a sharp angle to the 25-mm duct and directs the flow into a 150x25 mm duct at a 90-deg angle. The second honeycomb is 150x150, fused at a sharp angle to the 150x25mm duct and directs into the final duct.

Just a flat plate in front of the pipe exit.  Diffusers do this by design but none are probably designed for really high velocities.  Diffusers try to keep noise down, I doubt you really care about that.

A tube with small holes spaced at 7mm, the far end blocked.

Mike and Tiger -- thank you for the comments. I think a tube with the far end blocked and spaced holes may work. This is how round carbon and HEPA filters (and mufflers, as I learned today) work, and i have perforated tubes lying around.
